# Visual Studio (2017) - Git With Common Projects

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2017

I have a few common projects on my solution. This means that i use them from other solutions too and  i combined these common projects inside a common solution.

For example :

*Common.sln has CommonProject.csproj

*MySolution1.sln has ProjectA.csproj, ProjectB.csproj, CommonProject.csproj

*MySolution2.sln has ProjectX.csproj, ProjectY.csproj, CommonProject.csproj

I use git for source controller. (Bitbucket repos)

My problem is Git doesn't track my common projects on my solution1 and solution2.

Thanks for helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `CommonProject.csproj` doesn't exist in the local repositories' path for `solution1` and `solution2`.

And it seems you added `CommonProject.csproj` in `solution1` and `solution2` by Add -> Existing project. But by this way the `CommonProject.csproj` still located under `Common.sln`.

So you should copy the `CommonProject.csproj` under the directory of `solution1` and `solution2`, and then add project with the new path. Or you should add the repo which including `Common.sln` as the git submodule for `solution1` and `solution2`.

Comment: I think this one is better solution for my issue. Thank you for help"Or you should add the repo which including Common.sln as the git submodule for solution1 and solution2"  should i make this settings in git side or visual studio side ?

Comment: the settings is in git side. The `solution1` and `solution2` will treat the `Common.sln` as the library or third party code. More details about git submodules , you can refer https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules.